# Step into imported standard modules in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I wrote this simple code, using Visual Studio Code:

```py
import copy

a = 3
b = copy.copy(a)

print(b)
```

With the intention to see the internal works of copy.py when debugging.

Is that possible with Visual Studio Code? If so, how?

I placed a breakpoint at "import copy" and on the first line in copy.py (located at C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\copy.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vscode ignores standard libraries by default when debugging.

Add the following to your preferred Python debugger configuration in `launch.json`:

```
"debugStdLib": true
```

This is how mine looks:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "debugStdLib": true
        },
    ]
}
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2039#issuecomment-404925035